# Unity: change UI.Canvas.Text.text when space pressed

Tags: unity-game-engine, reference, null, instantiation

Class ChangeText is a child of a UI.Canvas.Text:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ChangeText : MonoBehaviour {

Text Instruction;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {        

    Instruction = GetComponent<Text>();

    Debug.Log("Instruction: " + Instruction.text);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

public void ChangeTheInstruction(string inst)
{
    Instruction.text = inst;
    Debug.Log("Instruction is now: " + Instruction.text);
}
}
```

The calling class SpacePress() calls ChangeText.ChangeTheInstruction() to change the Ui.Canvas.Text.text when the user presses the space bar. This class is a child of the main camera.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SpacePress : MonoBehaviour {

ChangeText CT;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("space"))
    {
        Debug.Log("Space pressed");

        CT.ChangeTheInstruction("NewInstruction");        
    }
}
}
```

I get a NullReferenceException from the CT object, because CT is not instantiated, but I cant use 'new' on a Monobehaviour. How do I do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

Either declare `CT` as public (or add the `[SerializeField]` tag above it), and drag & drop the gameObject holding the `ChangeText` component in the inspector.

```
public class SpacePress : MonoBehaviour 
{
    [SerializeField]
    private ChangeText CT; // Drag & drop in the inspector

}
```

Another solution (less advised), is to keep `CT` private and use one of the `GetComponent` or `Find` functions to retrieve it:

```
public class SpacePress : MonoBehaviour
{
    private ChangeText CT;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {
        CT = FindObjectOfType<ChangeText>();
        // OR
        // CT = GameObject.Find("NameOfTheObjectHoldingCT").GetComponent<ChangeText>();
    }
}
```

Comment: HI, I used:

CT = GameObject.Find("Text").GetComponent<ChangeText>();

in the start() method because ChangeText() is all ready added as a component for the Canvas.Text.

But I still get One NullReference error before I can change text. Can I solve this one off error?

Comment: `GameObject.Find` will retrieve **a** GameObject named `Text`. The problem is that you may retrieve the wrong gameObject. Rename the gameObject to have a unique name. But I highly advise you to go for the 1st solution.

Comment: I'd like to go for the first solution. but what do i drag to the inspector? the script is already there under the Text object.

Comment: As I said, you have to put a public / serialized reference of the `ChangeText` instance inside your `SpacePress` script. Then, drag & drop the object holding the `ChangeText` script inside the `CT` field inside the `SpacePress`'s inspector.